# Find duplicate groups of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates

I have a table with materials information where one material has from one to many constituents.

The table looks like this:

```
material_id contstiuent_id constituent_wt_pct
   1             1              10.5
   1             2              89.5
   2             1              10.5
   2             5              15.5
   2             7              74
   3             1              10.5
   3             2              89.5
```

Generally, I can have different material `ID`'s with the same constituents (both `ID`'s and weight percent), but also the same constituent id with the same weight percent can be in multiple materials.

I need to find the material `ID`'s that have exactly the same amount of constituents, same constituents id's and same weight percent (in the example of data that will be material ID 1 and 3)
What would be great is to have the output like:

> `ID    Duplicate ID's` 
>   `1      1,3` 
>   2      15,25 
>   ....

Just to clarify the question: I have several thousands of materials and it won't help me if I get just the id's of duplicate rows - I would like to see if it is possible to get the groups of duplicate material id's in the same row or field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a XML string in a CTE that contains all constituents and use that string to figure out what materials is duplicate.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eceb2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Materials
(
  material_id int, 
  constituent_id int, 
  constituent_wt_pct decimal(10, 2)
);


insert into Materials values
(1, 1, 10.5),
(1, 2, 89.5),
(2, 1, 10.5),
(2, 5, 15.5),
(2, 7, 74),
(3, 1, 10.5),
(3, 2, 89.5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with C as
(
  select M1.material_id,
        (
        select M2.constituent_id as I,
                M2.constituent_wt_pct as P
        from Materials as M2
        where M1.material_id = M2.material_id
        order by M2.constituent_id,
                 M2.material_id
        for xml path('')
        ) as constituents
  from Materials as M1
  group by M1.material_id
)
select row_number() over(order by 1/0) as ID,
       stuff((
       select ','+cast(C2.material_id as varchar(10))
       from C as C2
       where C1.constituents = C2.constituents
       for xml path('')
       ), 1, 1, '') as MaterialIDs
from C as C1
group by C1.constituents
having count(*) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eceb2/1/0)**:

```
| ID | MATERIALIDS |
--------------------
|  1 |         1,3 |
```

Comment: Mikael, thanks. What you got as a result are the constituents id's with associated weight percent and materials they were used.
I need to have almost reversed result - a table that will have 2 columns: 1 - row number (id), 2 - comma separated identical material id's (i.e have the same constituents and the same weight percent for each of them)

Comment: @user2250303 ok, I think I know what you want here. You want to find the materials that have the exact same components in them right? Like find all identical recipes for baking a cake where the cake In the way I'm thinking is the same as a material I your world and the constituent is the ingredients.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot - exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the following code to get the duplicate value,

```
Select EMP_NAME as NameT,count(EMP_NAME) as DuplicateValCount   From dbo.Emp_test
group by Emp_name having count(EMP_NAME) > 1
```